# Can we fast only for 1 day in muharram?

Tags: muharram

9th and 10th is recommended but what if a person cannot keep 2. So is it okay to fast for 1 day. 
Also, how important is neeyat in Islam?

Comment: You're asking two very different questions here, and showing no actual research effort. Please note that the Stack Exchange model is designed for *focussed questions* that can get *focussed answers*; we are not a typical Internet forum. I would strongly suggest you check out the advice in our help centre on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" to better understand the sorts of posts we encourage here and to focus your own post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarakatuhu 
In the name of Allah the most Gracious the most Merciful

FASTING

## Volume 3, Book 31, Number 222 :

Narrated by Ibn 'Abbas
    The Prophet came to Medina and saw the Jews fasting on the day of Ashura. He asked them about that. They replied, "This is a good day, the day on which Allah rescued Bani Israel from their enemy. So, Moses fasted this day." The Prophet said, "We have more claim over Moses than you." So, the Prophet fasted on that day and ordered (the Muslims) to fast (on that day).

'Abdullah ibn 'Abbas (may Allah be pleased with them both) said: "When the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) fasted on 'Ashura' and commanded the Muslims to fast as well, they said, 'O Messenger of Allah, it is a day that is venerated by the Jews and Christians.' The Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said, 'If I live to see the next year, in sha Allah, we will fast on the ninth day too.' But it so happened that the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) passed away before the next year came." [Reported by Muslim, 1916]
Ash-Shafi'i and his companions, Ahmad, Ishaq and others said: "It is mustahabb to fast on both the ninth and tenth days, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) fasted on the tenth, and intended to fast on the ninth."
On this basis it may be said that there are varying degrees of fasting 'Ashura', the least of which is to fast only on the tenth and the best of which is to fast the ninth as well. The more one fasts in Muharram, the better it is.

Shaykh ul-Islam said: "Fasting on the day of 'Ashura' is an expiation for a year, and it is not makruh to fast only that day … " [Al-Fatawa al-Kubra, part 5] In Tuhfat al-Muhtaj by Ibn Hajar al-Haytami, it says: "There is nothing wrong with fasting only on 'Ashura'." [Part 3, Bab Sawm at-Tatawwu']

Concluded that you can fast a single fast on tenth of muharram except if it (10th) is on friday keep two fast. (Either on thursday and friday or friday and saturday)

EDIT:-
Observe fasting on the day of `Ashura’, but differ from the Jews and fast one day before it and one day after it (Ahmad bin Hanbal, Baihaqi)

“Observe fasting on the day of Ashura , but differ from the Jews and fast the ninth and tenth days.” (Thirmidi)

INTENTIONS:-

On the authority of Omar bin Al-Khattab, who said : I heared the messenger of Allah salla Allah u alihi wa sallam say : "Actions are but by intention and every man shall have but that which he intended. Thus he whose migration was for Allah and His messenger, his migration was for Allah and His messenger, and he whose migration was to achieve some worldly benefit or to take some woman in marriage, his migration was for that for which he migrated."
[Bukhari]

There fore it plays an important role in Islam, your actions are completely based on your intentions it also counts on what you are thinkning to do, eg:- when you give a child candy what you intention is: 
1) to make the child happy
2) spending on him as charity
3) show others how good you are [showing off]

Answer (score 0):

**1. Fasting 9th and 10th**

Yes, it is ok to only fast in 10th, but it is preferable to fast 9th and 10th.

- Muslims fast in 10th because they believe that this
  was the day that Allah rescued Jews from Egyptians, this is the main
  purpose of this fasting.
- But later some people notified the
  prophet PBUH that Jews and Christians venerate this day, so he
  proposed also fasting in 9th just to be different from Christians
  and Jews.
  *BTW, in fact, Christians and Jews don't really venerate 10th of Muharram, they even don't follow Hijri calendar.*

**2. Intentions**

The intentions are very important in Islam, that's why the prophet PBUH said:

> The deeds are considered by the intentions, and a person will get the
>   reward according to his intention.
>   *[Al-Bukhari and Muslim]*